# Inject Interface implementation Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, inject

Hello I'm trying to inject an interface implementation of an EJB but I'm getting the error

```
Unsatisfied dependency for type personas.interfaces.IAdministracionPersonaLocal and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: personas.ejb.GestionPersonasBean#administracionPersonaBean
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[personas.ejb.GestionPersonasBean, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=personas.ejb.GestionPersonasBean]
```

Here is the code...

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class GestionPersonasBean {

    @Inject
    private IAdministracionPersonaLocal administracionPersonaBean;
}
```

My interface

```
@Local
public interface IAdministracionPersonaLocal {
// Some stuff
}
```

The EJB I'm trying to Inject

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AdministracionPersonaBean implements IAdministracionPersonaLocal {
// Some Stuff
}
```

I've used in the interface the @Remote annotation instead of @Local but nothing, same error.

Comment: Bad news. Quarkus does not support EJBs at all.  The `@Local` and `@Remote` annotations will be ignored.

Comment: Jan is correct in that Quarkus doesn't support EJBs. That said, the classes here are not EJBs (they are not `@Stateful` or `@Stateless` session beans, and they certainly are not MDBs or entity beans). The classes here are plain old CDI beans (with the useless `@Local` annotation on the interface that is ignored). The `IAdministracionPersonaLocal` interface _should_ be among the bean types of `AdministracionPersonaBean`, so this _should_ work. (Except Quarkus would warn that injecting to `private` fields is discouraged.) Could you provide a complete reproducer somewhere, e.g. on GitHub?

Comment: Thaks for the reply, I'm sorry but I cannot show full code here, because it is compay private, but the error is there, on that tree elements, I gonna delete de unnecesary annotation and make de Inject public, if it works I will reply.